# c# List with Arithmetic Operations

Tags: c#, list

I want realize arithmetic operations with my list, in this case:
Column "width" * Column "height" should re-Write the Column "Partial".
I have tried do a loop but It is not working.
I put a breakPoint at the row:

`_Area[i].Partial = _Area[i].width * _Area[i].height;`

And the debug never stop them I can think this line is not been readed.

This is my Collection View Model:

```
public class CollectionVM_Area : BindableBase
{
    private Values_Area _Area = new Values_Area();
    public Values_Area Area
    {
        get { return _Area; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Area, value); }
    }

    public CollectionVM_Area()
    {
        _Area.Add(new Area()
        {
            width=10, 
            height=11,
        });
        _Area.Add(new Area()
        {
            width=5, 
            height=5, 
            Partial=1,
        });

        bool NeedPartial = false;
        int i = 0;
        while (NeedPartial = false && i < _Area.Count)
        {
            if (_Area[i].Partida == true)
            {
                NeedPartial = true;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }

        if (NeedPartial==true)
        {
            _Area[i].Partial = _Area[i].width * _Area[i].height;
            NeedPartial = false;
        }
        else
        {
            NeedPartial = true;
        }
    }
}
```

My Project is a UWP but I think is no different in with a windows forms in lists, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the line `NeedPartial = false` executed? If so you should rebuild your project and debug again. Otherwise your `NeedPartial == true` (which can be simplified to `if (NeedPartial)` condition never passes.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, the line NeedPartial = false;
 under  _Area[i].Partial = _Area[i].width * _Area[i].height; is not executed.

Comment: Then the condition is not met, check `NeedPartial`s value. Is it `true`? I doubt so. Btw.: your final `else`-branch is obsolete because `NeedPartial` is not used any more (the same applies to the second statement in the last `if`-branch).

Comment: Your while loop "condition" is actually an assignment.

Comment: You should not add the anser to your question within the question itself. Either mark one answer as the one by accepting it or post your own one if you feel mine did not give all the information needed to solve the actual problem from the question. However you may upvote to your desires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two mistalkes in your code. First your `while`-loop makes an assignement instead of a comparisson (`=` towards `==`). Thus the first term within your while-condition allways evaluates to `false`. Secondly your calculation is located outside the loop causing the `NeedPartial`-value to be set but not never be read which I doubt is what you want.

Write this therefor:

```
bool NeedPartial = false;
int i = 0;
while (NeedPartial == false && i < _Area.Count) // or even simpler: while (!NeedPartial ...)
{
    if (_Area[i].Partida == true) // or simply: if (_Area[i].Partida) { ... }
    {
        NeedPartial = true;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }

    if (NeedPartial==true) // if (NeedPartial) ...
    {
        _Area[i].Partial = _Area[i].width * _Area[i].height;
        NeedPartial = false;
    }
    else
    {
        NeedPartial = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: Answered.

The Correct Loop is:

```
 bool NeedPartial = false;
            int i = 0;
            while (!NeedPartial && i < _Area.Count)
            {
                if (_Area[i].Partida)
                {
                    NeedPartial = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    i++;
                }
                if (NeedPartial)
                {
                    _Area[i].Partial = _Area[i].width * _Area[i].height;
                    NeedPartial = false;
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    NeedPartial = true;
                }
            }
```

Thanks to HimBromBeere for your help.